# column-wise extracting of list of list of tuples in python

Tags: python, list

all I have a list of list of tuple here

```
A =[[(1, 52), (1, 12), (-1, -1)],[(-1, 23), (1, 42), (-1, -1)],[(1, -1), (-1, -1), (1, 42)]]
```

I wanted get the tuples containing the max values in second element of the tuple, column-wise.

I tried accessing columns like this

`A[:,2]`

But I get the error

> TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple

Thanks in advance, Please let me know if you need any other information

Edit 1:

Desired output:

```
[(1, 52),(1, 42),(1, 42)]
```

Comment: Please post your desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[max(a,key=lambda x:x[1]) for a in zip(*A)]
```

output:

```
[(1, 52), (1, 42), (1, 42)]
```

Let me know if this works for you I will explain the answer.

You can access columns like this..

```
>>> list(zip(*A)[0])
[(1, 52), (-1, 23), (1, -1)]
>>> list(zip(*A)[1])
[(1, 12), (1, 42), (-1, -1)]
```

---

**Explanation**
**zip** https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip

```
>>> x=[1,2,3]
>>> y=['a','b','c']
>>> z=['first','second','third']
>>> zip(x,y,z)
[(1, 'a', 'first'), (2, 'b', 'second'), (3, 'c', 'third')]
```

Now imagine x,y,z being the rows you had in `A`. By zip(rows) it returns 1st elements, 2nd elements, 3rd elements etc... There by returning us columns of the rows we passed.
Note: zip acts on multiple arguments passed in so we need to send multiple rows like x,y,z separately, not like [x,y,z] as a list. That is done by *A which separates the rows and passes to zip.

Now we got different columns

**max**https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max

```
max(1,2)                      #Will return 2
max(cars,lambda x:x.speed)    #Will give you the fastest car
max(cars,lambda x:x.capacity) #Will give you the biggest passenger car
max(tups,lambda x:x[1])       #Will give you the tuple with biggest 2nd element
```

**List Comprehension**https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

```
A=[1,2,3]
[x**2 for x in A]     #Will give you [1,4,9]
[x**3 for x in A]     #Will give you [1,8,27]
```

Finally

```
[max(a,key=lambda x:x[1]) for a in zip(*A)]
```

Will give you max for each column!

Comment: Thanks a lot!.It works. Can you please provide a brief explanation of all your methods. I am curious to know.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
A =[[(1, 52), (1, 12), (-1, -1)],[(-1, 23), (1, 42), (-1, -1)],[(1, -1), (-1, -1), (1, 42)]]

new_A = [max(a, key=lambda x: x[-1]) for a in zip(*A)]
```

Output:

```
[(1, 52), (1, 42), (1, 42)]
```

Answer (score 1):

`A` is a list is lists of tuples. Basic Python does not recognised multiple-element subscripting, although Numpy and similar modules extend it. Your subscript expression `:,2` is therefore interpreted as a tuple whose first element is a lice and whose second element is an integer, which (as the message explains) is not acceptable as a list index.

Unfortunately, "the tuples containing the max values in second element of the tuple, column-wise" isn't a terribly good description of the actual desired result.

I presume the answer you would like is `[(1, 52), (1, 42), (1, 42)]`.

One relatively simple way to achieve this is to sort each of the sub-lists separately, taking the last element of each. this could be spelled as

```
result = [sorted(x, key=lambda z: z[1])[-1] for x in A]
```

The `key` argument to the `sorted` function ensures that each list is sorted on its second element, the 
`[-1]` subscript takes the last (and therefore highest) element of the sorted list, and the `for x in A` ensure that each element of the output corresponds to an element (*i.e.*, a list of three tuples) of the input.

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer I have added expected output to my question :)